# Change ownership of one single VM in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

How to change ownership/migrate single VM from one GCP account to another GCP account?

I don't mean between projects, but between two different GCP accounts. 
I now that is possible to migrate whole project between two different GCP accounts, but not sure if it possible do just with VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not pretty sure what you mean by changing the ownership of the Google Cloud Instance. Do you want to change your instance to another project that belongs to another GCP account? If so, you can [create](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images#bundle_image) an image of the persistent disk of your instance, [export](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image) the image and then import it to the project that owns the other GCP account.